Why 010editor read .bin file as 1byte and 2byte?
I got .bin files and I opened it by "010 Editor" on Mac.
And I saw some .bin files read as 1byte but some files are 2byte.
It means that, commonly Number 2 is 0x32 but some file wrote Number 2 as 0x32 0x00 (it's little endian right?)
And I don't know how "010 Editor" decide to read .bin file as 1byte or 2byte. It doesn't have any header or something. Am I wrong??
additionally, the .bin files are come from same Application. decoding apk by apktool.
I want to know how 010 editor works and what's difference between 1byte bin file and 2byte bin file.

I got it. It's because BOM of UTF-16. The binary file that reads 2byte starts with "FF FE" and it means, encoding type is utf-16 so the editor read this binary file as 2byte.
